# How to calculate CRC that's used in printer inf file?

Tags: windows, printing, crc, inf

As mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/identifiers-generated-by-usbprint-sys, Windows calculte a CRC value according to printer's manufacturer name and the model of the device to match the printer driver. But how to calculate it? I try many ways but still can't get the same result as the example that's given by Microsoft.

Comment: It does say you can check a .log file to find it. How many CRC16 & 32 functions have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

[This document](http://www.osdever.net/documents/PNP-Parellel-v1.0b.pdf) provides code to compute the CRC. Note that the example given on your linked page is fake -- the CRC is *not* 3115. Do you have any examples of actual IDs that you're trying to match?

Comment: Thank you very much，the document is want i am looking for！